# Best way to check if a string contains another string

Tags: php

`$name` are strings, contains file names are something like below,

> AAA_ss_01.pdf, AAA_ss_02.pdf, AAA_sd_01.pdf, BBB_ss_02.pdf,
>   BBB_ss_4.pdf, BBB_sd_01.pdf, cc_saa_01.pdf

I'd like to add an input name value to classify items automatically.

```
<input name="AAA" .../> or <input name="BBB" .../> ........
```

PHP

```
if (strpos($names, 'AAA') !== false) {
    echo 'AAA';
}elseif (strpos($names, 'BBB') !== false){
    echo 'BBB';
}elseif (strpos($names, 'ccc') !== false){
    echo 'ccc';
}else{
    echo '';
}
```

I make a function like this

```
function contains($names, $string){
    if (strpos($names, $string) !== false) {
        echo $string;
    }
}
```

but I am not sure if strpos is a right method I could use or there is a better one.

Thanks

Comment: It seems that $name is a string, not an array. It it right?

Comment: How do you wanna classify the files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`strpos`](https://www.php.net/strpos) is the correct method to check if string A contains string B. It is extremely fast. You may want to use [`stripos`](https://www.php.net/stripos) for case insensitive matching instead.

However, if `$names` is an array, you must iterate over it and check every value.

```
foreach ($names as $name) {
  if (strpos($name, 'AAA') !== false) {
    echo 'AAA';
  } elseif (strpos($name, 'BBB') !== false) {
    echo 'BBB';
  } elseif (strpos($name, 'ccc') !== false) {
    echo 'ccc';
  } else{
    echo '';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're just looking to make an input out of the first 3 letters, you can do it quickly using the following:

```
foreach($names as $name):
    echo '<input name="', substr($name, 0, 3) ,'" type="text"/>';
endforeach;
```

Comment: I think you have to explode the original string $name to built the array $names before the foreach statement